# AWS S3 website access restriction to only users that are signed in into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have a simple management website hosted on s3, bucket is not public.
The url is something like https://whatever.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/page.html
By default when I open this website on a browser I get access denied - which is great, but because I am already logged in into my aws account, would it be possible to get access?

Comment: No, there's no connection between the AWS console application and your statically hosted S3 site.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the bucket access to public, you can use [CloudFront + CloudFront OAI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to restrict the bucket access only throw CloudFront.

And in CloudFront, you can specify your limits more easily with [CloudFront + WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html).

Comment: This won't provide the desired access that leverages the fact that you are logged into the AWS console.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing Amazon S3 via an "anonymous" URL (which does not identify you), it is not possible to control *who* can see the content. It's basically public or private.

However, applications can generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that allow private objects to be temporarily accessed, which is great for things like giving access to private photos and documents (much like how you can generate a link in Dropbox-style systems to get access to a private file). But... this is typically done when a back-end application is generating the pages. It isn't appropriate when merely navigating through static pages served from Amazon S3.

However, none of these methods can use an "AWS console login" to control access, since that requires cookies that are within the console's domain space. You really need a traditional back-end that uses authentication and cookies to manage access.